# Given 3 cross products of 3 vectors, how do you solve an expression of this format?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

If you're given:

$$a \times b = (2, -4, 2),\quad a \times c = (7, 13, -11),\quad b \times c = (1, 7, 1)$$

what properties of cross products or formulas can you use to solve $(2b - c) \times (3a + 5c)$?

I want to utilize how there is a $c$ common to both vector arithmetics but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Just break it into pieces, using $a\times(b+c)=a\times b+a\times c$.
What do you know that relates $a\times b$ with $b\times a$?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how to break things up. Using that formula was my first thought. I end up with `3((2b-c) x a) + 5((2b-c) x c)` which doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: @OP The cross product is compatible with scalar multiplication: $\,\alpha\mathbf u\times \mathbf v=\mathbf u\times \alpha \mathbf v=\alpha (\mathbf u \times \mathbf v)$.